# Unix delete line containing more than one dash

Tags: regex, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have around 12 million lines in a file and would like to delete the lines which contain more than one dash. A couple of examples:

```
e--xa-mple
e-xa-mple
```

There are any variations possible. Sed, awk, grep or anything else will work.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play with the number of fields that you get setting dash as field separator :

```
awk -F- 'NF<=2' file
```

And to replace the current file, you can do:

```
awk -F- 'NF<=2' file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file
```

#### Explanation

- `-F-` sets `-` as field separator.
- `NF` stands for number of fields.
- `NF<=2` is true when the number of fields is 1 or 2, which means the line contains 0 or 1 dashes. Hence, it won't print any of the lines that have more than two fields, that is, 2 or more dashes.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
e--xa-mple
e-xa-mple
example
e-xample

$ awk -F- 'NF<=2' a
example
e-xample
```

Comment: `awk -F- 'NF<3'` could be used :)

Comment: Yeah, or `awk -F- '! (NF>2)'` :D I prefer to indicate the limit of what I want rather than the first one I don't want. But of course, everyone to his own taste :)

Comment: can the line be deleted instead of replaced with blank?

Answer (score 5):

Simple one in sed:

```
sed '/-.*-/d' yourfile
```

or faster, avoiding to scan the whole line when second dash present:

```
sed '/-[^-]*-/d' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

with one-liner `perl`

```
perl -ne "print unless /-.*-/" file
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose someone should put

```
grep -v '-.*-'
```

in here as well, even though I'd personally use the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) answer from @Gilles Arcas